# C# TextRenderer text black shadows

Tags: c#, gdi

I have a project the put random quotes on desktop wallpapers, you can position them, top or bottom. Anyhow, the text works great when using DrawText, but since it is required to have a custom alignment, LEFT, CENTER, or RIGHT.. I moved to using TextRenderer.

below is the screen shot, and if you notice, there is a transparent horizontal box along the screen with text.
[image]
but since Stackoverflow is crashing everytime I upload a HiRes image, I just resized it and just show this to you
[image]
notice the black shadows around the characters? How do I get rid of that?

-----------------
solved by adding

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1578056/566608 it suggest you how to adjust the aliasing by using DrawString instead

Comment: g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias; saves the problem