# Trying to add transparent text with TextRenderer.DrawText to a bitmap image

Tags: c#, gdi

I'm actually trying to add some text to an image in C# with

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.DrawText(Graphics, string, Rectangle, Color, TextFormaFlags)
```

I prepare my image (which is a png) by loading it in memory, with something similar to

```
Image image = ImageCache.Get(...);
bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
```

I then draw my text with the above command. The problem is that whatever I use for the color,  even something like

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0,255,255,255)
```

the transparency is not drawn. I tried many settings for

```
graphics.TextRenderingHint
```

and different combinations of fonts, transparency level, etc. Is there something I don't understand here? Any hint is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `Color.Transparent` as `BackColor` or use `Graphics.DrawString`. See: [TextRenderer.DrawText in Bitmap vs OnPaintBackground](http://stackoverflow.com/q/849531/880990)

Comment: If you want alpha blending effects then you must use Graphics.DrawString(), TextRenderer uses GDI which is limited to RGB.

Comment: @Hans Passant Well, not the answer I wanted to hear, but good to know. If you put it as a formal answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I avoid posting answers that nobody wants to hear.  You can post it yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments : if you try to draw transparent text with

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.DrawText
```

because you look for the advantages brought by GDI in C#, you just can't. Use

```
System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString
```

instead, even if the result for the word-wrapping is slightly inferior with GDI+.